# underscore for multiple nested level arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, underscore.js

I have an array of object, and i want to convert it into a map of key value pairs with the `id` as the key. However, I want to do it for both the root level and within the `recipes` attribute.

**Array `resp`**:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "recipes": [
      {
        "id": 4036
      },
      {
        "id": 4041
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "recipes": [
      {
        "id": 4052
      },
      {
        "id": 4053
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Desired Result**

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": "1",
    "recipes": {
      "4036": {
        "id": 4036
      },
      "4041": {
        "id": 4041
      }
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "2",
    "recipes": {
      "4052": {
        "id": 4052
      },
      "4053": {
        "id": 4053
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

I know how to do so using lodash through the following function:

*Using Underscore.js*

```
function deepKeyBy(arr, key) {
  return _(arr)
    .map(function(o) { // map each object in the array
      return _.mapValues(o, function(v) { // map the properties of the object
        return _.isArray(v) ? deepKeyBy(v, key) : v; // if the property value is an array, run deepKeyBy() on it
      });
    })
    .keyBy(key); // index the object by the key
}
```

For this project, however, I'm looking for an an elegant solution using underscore to do the same thing - make all the objects nested within the array use `id` as key. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Added the desired output format

Comment: can you show the structure of the intended result?

Comment: @hackerrdave I've added the desired result above

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Array.reduce` on the response and a nested `Array.reduce` on the recipes to produce the desired result. Here is an es6 example:

```
resp.reduce((p, c) => {
  p[c.id] = {
    id: c.id,
    recipes: c.recipes.reduce((r, cr) => {
       r[cr.id] = { id: cr.id }
       return r;
    }, {})
  }
  return p;
}, {});
```

A more verbose and non-es6 version:

```js
var resp = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "recipes": [
      {
        "id": 4036
      },
      {
        "id": 4041
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "recipes": [
      {
        "id": 4052
      },
      {
        "id": 4053
      }
    ]
  }
]    

var formatted = resp.reduce(function(data, cur) {
  data[cur.id] = {
    id: cur.id,
    recipes: cur.recipes.reduce(function(recips, curRecip) {
       recips[curRecip.id] = { id: curRecip.id }
       return recips;
    }, {})
  }
  return data;
}, {});

console.log(formatted);
```

If you *must* use underscore, you could wrap `resp` and `c.recipes`:

```
_(resp).reduce((p, c) => {
  p[c.id] = {
    id: c.id,
    recipes: _(c.recipes).reduce((r, cr) => {
       r[cr.id] = { id: cr.id }
       return r;
    }, {})
  }
  return p;
}, {});
```